# Get the list of all Modules inside the Project on ThirdWeb

Tags: javascript, web3js

I was ultimately trying to get the list of all the modules I created inside my Project over the ThirdWeb.com dashboard and filter out the NFT collections out of it. So I asked on discord and someone told me to use the getAllModulesMetadata() to do so, I did something like this

```
const sdk = new ThirdwebSDK();

const NftModules = sdk
    .getAppModule("<Project Address>")
    .getAllModuleMetadata([ModuleType.NFT]);
```

I also did something like this but getting the same issue.

```
const sdk = new ThirdwebSDK();

async function getAllModules() {
    const NftModules = await sdk
      .getAppModule("<Project Address>")
      .getAllModuleMetadata([ModuleType.NFT]);
}

getAllModules();
```

Now it gives this error 
Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: call revert exception (method="getAllModulesOfType(uint256)", errorArgs=null, errorName=null, errorSignature=null, reason=null, code=CALL_EXCEPTION, version=abi/5.5.0)

Is something wrong? Any help will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass in an RPC url or a signer in the `ThirdwebSDK()` constructor before you can use modules:

- An RPC URL (which means the sdk is in read-only mode, you won't be able to change state of things on-chain, only fetch it). You can either use something like [alchemy](https://alchemy.com) or use a public RPC for that particular chain.
- A valid ethers signer (which could be connected from metamask, [magiclink](https://magic.link), coinbase wallet, etc)
- A valid `ethers.Wallet` object, which can be initialised from a private key

```js
const sdk = new ThirdwebSDK("your_rpc_url_or_signer");
```

Let me know if you still face any issues!